# Compare-Object returning unexpected output

Tags: powershell, compareobject

I have created a small function that captures `Get-Volume` into a local file. The next time the function runs, it compares the output of a fresh `Get-Volume` with the one previously saved to the file system.

This function works perfectly for services but is strangely returning a volume as 'different' even though we can see from the output it is not.

```
function Compare-Volumes{
    $Path = "$Env:PROGRAMDATA\VACS\states\"
    $File = "volumes.csv"
    $Volumes = Get-Volume | Select-Object OperationalStatus, HealthStatus, DriveType, FileSystemType, DedupMode, UniqueId, AllocationUnitSize, DriveLetter, FileSystem, FileSystemLabel, Size

    if (![System.IO.File]::Exists($Path+$File)){
        $Volumes | Export-CSV -Path $Path$File -Force
    }else{
        # Load file to object, get differences, submit to API, replace previous snapshot in file with new one
        $Snapshot = Import-CSV -Path "$Path$File"
        $StatusChanges = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($Snapshot) -DifferenceObject ($Volumes) -Property OperationalStatus, HealthStatus, DriveType, FileSystemType, DedupMode, UniqueId, AllocationUnitSize, DriveLetter, FileSystem, FileSystemLabel, Size -IncludeEqual
        $StatusChanges
        $Volumes | Export-CSV -Path $Path$File -Force
    }
}
```

My expected results are that everything returns as equal/unchanged (`==`) as none of the properties change, as is clear in the output below. Yet for some reason, the `SideIndicator` property added by `Compare-Object` is indicating value differences for the volume labelled `Recovery`.

```
OperationalStatus  : Unknown
HealthStatus       : Healthy
DriveType          : CD-ROM
FileSystemType     : Unknown
DedupMode          : Disabled
UniqueId           : \\?\Volume{2b4803c9-1ebe-11e6-9bed-005056c00008}\
AllocationUnitSize : 0
DriveLetter        : E
FileSystem         : 
FileSystemLabel    : 
Size               : 0
SideIndicator      : ==

OperationalStatus  : OK
HealthStatus       : Healthy
DriveType          : Fixed
FileSystemType     : NTFS
DedupMode          : NotAvailable
UniqueId           : \\?\Volume{f688d14f-0ee7-11e5-b210-806e6f6e6963}\
AllocationUnitSize : 4096
DriveLetter        : C
FileSystem         : NTFS
FileSystemLabel    : Windows
Size               : 953903214592
SideIndicator      : ==

OperationalStatus  : Unknown
HealthStatus       : Healthy
DriveType          : CD-ROM
FileSystemType     : Unknown
DedupMode          : Disabled
UniqueId           : \\?\Volume{f688d152-0ee7-11e5-b210-806e6f6e6963}\
AllocationUnitSize : 0
DriveLetter        : D
FileSystem         : 
FileSystemLabel    : 
Size               : 0
SideIndicator      : ==

OperationalStatus  : OK
HealthStatus       : Healthy
DriveType          : Fixed
FileSystemType     : NTFS
DedupMode          : NotAvailable
UniqueId           : \\?\Volume{f688d14e-0ee7-11e5-b210-806e6f6e6963}\
AllocationUnitSize : 4096
DriveLetter        : 
FileSystem         : NTFS
FileSystemLabel    : Recovery
Size               : 6291451904
SideIndicator      : =>

OperationalStatus  : OK
HealthStatus       : Healthy
DriveType          : Fixed
FileSystemType     : NTFS
DedupMode          : NotAvailable
UniqueId           : \\?\Volume{f688d14e-0ee7-11e5-b210-806e6f6e6963}\
AllocationUnitSize : 4096
DriveLetter        : 
FileSystem         : NTFS
FileSystemLabel    : Recovery
Size               : 6291451904
SideIndicator      : <=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely it is the DriveLetter property which compares falsely
with volumes which doesn't have one (like the recovery partition).

Presumably you'll have to include a Select-Object with a calculated property
which also checks the DriveLetter `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()`
to avoid comparing $Null with the stringified output `""` of Export-Csv

Your script, a bit streamlined:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\12\31\SO_53990220.ps1

function Compare-Volumes{
    $FilePath = Join-Path "$Env:PROGRAMDATA\VACS\states\" "volumes.csv"

    $Volumes = Get-Volume | Select-Object OperationalStatus,HealthStatus,DriveType,
        FileSystemType, DedupMode,UniqueId,AllocationUnitSize,FileSystemLabel,FileSystem,Size,
        @{n='DriveLetter';e={if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.DriveLetter)){""}else{$_.DriveLetter}}}

    if (Test-Path $FilePath){
        # Load file to object, get differences, submit to API, replace previous snapshot in file with new one
        $Snapshot = Import-CSV -Path $FilePath
        $StatusChanges = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($Snapshot) -DifferenceObject ($Volumes) `
          -IncludeEqual -Property OperationalStatus,HealthStatus,DriveType,FileSystemType,
          DedupMode,UniqueId,AllocationUnitSize,FileSystemLabel,FileSystem,Size,
          DriveLetter
        $StatusChanges
    }
    $Volumes | Export-CSV -Path $FilePath -Force -NoTypeInformation
}

Compare-Volumes
```

Comment: Your understanding of my question and the quality of your response is outstanding, thank you! I'm an Infrastructure Engineer slowly moving towards automation and development, your feedback here has significantly helped. Thanks again!

Comment: Ignore and remove  that line for my local testing, also remove the # to uncomment your original line

Comment: Just to explain the `(gi .).FullName` -> gi is an alias for Get-Item, the dot represents the current folder, enclosing in parentheses is equivalent to `Select-Object -Expandproperty` with the named property `.FullName`